# How can I implement my code to get restart in my Tic tac toe game?

Tags: python

I need to get restart of my tic tac toe game after the match declare the 
winner i am getting a restart option too but my code is why not getting restart. I want my code to be contain from first when the game over and I have already used function but it is only showing the result of the game when I ask it to get restart.

```
#Making a Game board 

game_is_on = True
current_player = 'x'
winner = None

def restart():
    print("\n")
    print ("***********Let's play our game**********")
    board=[ '-','-','-',
            '-','-','-',
            '-','-','-']





    def display_board():

        print('\n')
        print (board[0]+' | '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+'   | 1 | 2 | 3 |')
        print (board[3]+' | '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+'   | 4 | 5 | 6 |')
        print (board[6]+' | '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+'   | 7 | 8 | 9 |')
        print('\n')
    display_board()


    def play_game():
        while game_is_on:
            handle_turn(current_player)
            cheak_if_game_over()
            flip_player()



        if winner == 'x' or winner == 'o':
            print(winner + ' won the match' + ' try next time ' + current_player)
            '''restart = 'yes'
            while True:

                if restart == 'yes':
                    restart = input("Do you want to play again:")
                    continue
                elif restart == 'no':
                    print("player don't want to play")
                    break'''

        else:
            print("Match Draw")





    def handle_turn(player):
        print(current_player+"'s turn..")
        postion=input("Enter a number form 1-9:")
        valid=False
        while not valid:
            while postion not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
                postion=input("Please insert a number from 1-9:")
            postion=int(postion)-1
            if board[postion] == '-':
                valid = True
            else:
                print("You have already insert this number...")
            board[postion]=player

            display_board()


    def cheak_if_game_over():
        cheak_for_winner()
        cheak_if_tie()


    def cheak_for_winner():
        global winner
        row_winner = cheak_row()
        column_winner = cheak_column()
        diagonal_winner = cheak_diagonal()


        if row_winner:
            winner = row_winner
        elif column_winner:
            winner = column_winner
        elif diagonal_winner:
            winner = diagonal_winner
        else:
            winner=None

    def cheak_row():
        global game_is_on
        row_1 = board[0] == board[1] == board[2] != '-'
        row_2 = board[3] == board[4] == board[5] != '-'
        row_3 = board[6] == board[7] == board[8] != '-'

        if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
            game_is_on =False
        if row_1:
            return board[0]
        elif row_2:
            return board[3]
        elif row_3:
            return board[6]
        return


    def cheak_column():
        global game_is_on
        column_1 = board[0] == board[3] == board[6] != '-'
        column_2 = board[1] == board[4] == board[7] != '-'
        column_3 = board[2] == board[5] == board[8] != '-'

        if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
            game_is_on = False
            if column_1:
                return board[0]
            elif column_2:
                return board[1]
            elif column_3:
                return board[2]
            return

    def cheak_diagonal():
            global game_is_on
            diagonal_1 = board[0] == board[4] == board[8] != '-'
            diagonal_2 = board[6] == board[4] == board[2] != '-'

            if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
                game_is_on = False
            if diagonal_1:
                return board[0]
            elif diagonal_2:
                return board[6]
            return

    def cheak_if_tie():
        global game_is_on
        if '-' not in board:
                game_is_on = False
        else:
            return

    def flip_player():
        global current_player

        if current_player =='x':
                current_player='o'
        elif current_player=='o':
            current_player='x'
        else:
            return

    play_game()

    run_again = input("Do you want to restart it:")
    if run_again=='yes'.lower():
        restart()
    elif run_again=='no'.lower():
        print("player don't want to play")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

restart()
```

And here I didn't get any error I want to just restart my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    # do something
    end_program = input("Do you want to quit? Y/N: ")
    if end_program == "Y":
        break
```

you could try this, it will keep the program going in a loop forever until the user chooses to end it. You can pretty it up with some print statements and other choices.

If you really want the program to be restarted, you could have a main.py file, and then a game.py file.

```
import subprocess

while True:
    subprocess.run(["python", "game.py"])
    program_break = input("Do you want to play again? Y/N: ")
    if program_break == "Y":
        break
```